# Delete Assets input fields in a front-end form

Tags: assets, forms, zoo-visitor, jquery, javascript

I have the following in a Zoo Visitor Update form:

```
<label class="control-label" for="member_photo">Performer / Band Photo</label>

    <input type="hidden" name="member_photo[]" value="0"/>

    {member_photo}<div><img src="{url}" width="150" /><input type="hidden" name="member_photo[]" value="{file_id}"/> (To delete this just remove the hidden input for this image)</div>{/member_photo}

    <p><input type="file" name="member_photo[]" id="member_photo" multiple></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="member_photo_filedir" value="8">
```

I need users to be able to remove images as well as adding new ones.

As per the bracketed comment, P&T have suggested that in order to remove the input I need something like a 'delete' checkbox that toggles the name of the input but this is beyond my limited js-fu and will no doubt be useful to others too.

Any jquery ninjas able to offer up a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to output a delete button/checkbox alongside each image/input. You can then use jQuery to remove that img/input from the DOM so when you submit the form it's no longer there.

Maybe something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="member_photo[]" value="0"/>

{member_photo}<div><img src="{url}" width="150" /><input type="hidden" name="member_photo[]" value="{file_id}"/> (To delete this just remove the hidden input for this image) <button class="delete-img">Delete</button> </div>{/member_photo}

<p><input type="file" name="member_photo[]" id="member_photo" multiple></p>

<input type="hidden" name="member_photo_filedir" value="8">



$('.delete-img').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().remove();
    $(this).remove();
})
```

*Added '()' after function from first post.*

Comment: This works - just needed to add () after function :)
Thanks so much.

Comment: Heh, I wasnt writing in a code editor :)

Comment: Just looking now you could use '$(this).parent().remove()' and get rid of the full div instead.

Comment: Yep, that works. Excellent

Answer (score 1):

Darren used a button, which should work too, but here's the jQuery I came up with to remove the name attribute value:

HTML:

```
<label class="control-label" for="member_photo">Performer / Band Photo</label>

    <input type="hidden" name="member_photo[]" value="0"/>

    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" width="150" />
        <input type="hidden" name="member_photo[]" value="{file_id}" id="photo" /> <br>
        (To delete this just remove the hidden input for this image)
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" name="remove_file"> Remove file

    <p><input type="file" name="member_photo[]" id="member_photo" multiple></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="member_photo_filedir" value="8">
```

jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $('input#photo').val('');
});
```

(Note that I gave the image an ID.)

Comment: Hi Angie. This works for a single image but with multiple images, removes them all. I can see how this could be modified to work with multiple images but the below solution works so I'll move on for now. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't realize you were trying to remove multiple images.

Comment: Sorry, should have made that clear. Definitely keeping that one in the locker for next time though ; )

Answer (score 1):

Should use 'change' event instead of click. Cause user may not select any new file, then it will remove the existing file.

```
<img src="{url}" />
<input type="hidden" name="member_photo" value="{file_id}" id="cur_file_id">
<input type="file" name="member_photo" id="file_upload">
<input type="hidden" name="member_photo_filedir" value="8">`
<pre><code>{/member_photo}</code></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#file_upload").change(function (){
    $('#cur_file_id').val('');
  });
</script>
```